# Object intrinsic monitor as java.util.concurrent.Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I believe it could be very useful to be able to use an object's monitor as a `Lock`. That is :

```
synchronized(object) {
    ...
}
```

would be equivalent to :

```
lock.lock();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

As far as i understand it, it is not possible to achieve this using `Lock` interface since synchronization only happens in blocks.
A solution i see would be to have `java.lang.Object` be enriched with an extra method

```
public Lock asLock/getIntrinsicMonitorObject(); // Name isn't perfect but i'm not asking for that
```

or something like :

```
LockSupport.getIntrinsicMonitorObject(Object of);
```

---

Questions :

- Is there some good reasons it isn't possible to do this for now (i consider the fact that some `tryLock` isn't currently possible with synchronization isn't one)
- Is there some solution to do it using existing JRE classes ?
- Would a JSR on this make sense ?

Comment: I don't think you'll ever see such a dependency of the core `Object` on the `java.util.concurrent` API. That would severely maim any attempts to produce a minimal JDK profile for embedded applications.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a method of Object. `Lock lock = Lock.getMonitorLock(object);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unsafe` class* has some support to directly manipulate monitors:

```
public native void monitorEnter(Object o);

public native void monitorExit(Object o);

public native boolean tryMonitorEnter(Object o);
```

<sub>*that's in Java 8 but I think it was already there in Java 7</sub>

Comment: Java 6 already had it as well, right next to their version of `sneakyThrow` :). http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java#Unsafe.monitorEnter%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I had never paid attention to that method!

Comment: Great ! I checked and saw these Unsafe methods aren't available on android. Is there some other way to do the same on android ?