# Is it possible to access Dalvik VM from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'd like to be able to target the Dalvik VM using native code in Android.
This means using native classes that are listed in [platform/dalvik](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/) under android sources repositories.

In particular, i'd like to call `Sync.dvmLockObject` and its counterpart `Sync.dvmUnlockObject`.

Is it possible ? Could you provide a quick snippet of code, or instructions for particular libraries to include ?

*Alternatively, you can provide a java, or native code alternative that does the same (that is, be able to access a java object's monitor. Using `pthread` for example doesn't seem to be appropriated for example).*

Comment: Isn't this just `MonitorEnter` and `MonitorExit` from JNI?

Comment: This is just what i figured out some minutes ago :s

Answer (score 1):

You can use JNI [FindClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16027) to find any private class of the framework, and find and call its methods the usual JNI way. But [dvmLockObject()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik-snapshot/+/gingerbread/vm/Sync.h) is not a method of `Sync` class. It is part of the dalvik native libraries. You can call it as a usual C function from your code. You will link to `libdvm.so`, as to any other system library.

But I don't know what useful purpose there can be in calling this function.

Comment: Thanks ! I'd like to manipulate java monitors objects as `java.util.concurrent.Lock`, here's another post that explains the idea : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375370/object-intrinsic-monitor-as-java-util-concurrent-lock?noredirect=1#comment34015571_22375370

Comment: Could you please give me some more hint ? I'm confused about how to obtain the structures needed to actually make the invocation (`Object *`, `Monitor *` for example) which are part of `libdvm.so`

Comment: Thanks to [@fadden](http://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden), we now understand that there is no real justification for the hard work of manipulating dalvik private objects!