# Calling Dalvik Stack from native code

Tags: android, native, dalvik

I am using JNI with Android Studio 1.5.1 targeting Android API 18 and my questions are:

Q.1) How can I call Dalvik internal functions from native code?

For example in the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/android-4.3.1_r1/vm/interp/), in the interpreter module, in the stack.cpp, how can I call the function dvmDumpThreadStack(const DebugOutputTarget* target, Thread* thread) from native code?

It seems that I need to include some files and link to some libraries as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22399436/is-it-possible-to-access-dalvik-vm-from-native-code) but I need specific details. Which files do I need to link to and which files do I need to include in my native code to successfully call the dvmDumpThreadStack function for example?

This is the content of the Andorid.md file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyLibrary.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Q.2) How to define the required arguments with the required values to call Dalvik internal functions? For example, before I call the dvmDumpThreadStack function, how to define target and thread and which values to store in them before I call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't.  They're called "internal" functions for a reason.

If you're really determined to do this, you can find the function pointers by using `dlsym()` to find the address at runtime.  You'll need the "mangled" name, which you can get by examining the binary with `nm`.  (This was easier before the code was switched from C to C++ back in 4.1 or thereabouts.)  You can get the Thread* the same way the VM does it, by calling one of the `dvmGetThread` functions in Thread.cpp (`dvmGetThreadByHandle`, `dvmGetThreadByThreadId`, `dvmGetThreadFromThreadObject`), or by calling `dvmThreadSelf()` if you're interested in the current thread.  Pass that to `dvmDumpThread()`, which will set up the `DebugOutputTarget` so you don't have to.

You don't need a header file that defines Thread* to pass a Thread* around.  Just declare the thread-getter functions as returning void*, and the thread-dump function as accepting a void* argument.  If you're worried about type-safety and portability, don't call internal VM functions from an app.

The one time I actually wanted to do this -- debugging something, don't remember what -- I actually added a new `extern "C"` function to the VM that took no arguments and just dumped the current thread's stack.  That made everything much easier.

Comment: Do you mean to call like this:  

dvmDumpThreadStack(dvmDumpThread(dvmThreadSelf(),false), dvmThreadSelf() ) but using dlsym() to get the functions pointers

Comment: Also dlsym() requires a file handle to the object file. And finding a handle to the Dalvik Stack.o object file does not seem to work: 

handle = dlopen("Stack.o",RTLD_NOW);
func = (void (*)()) dlsym(handle,"dvmDumpThreadStack");

Comment: Check the man page for `dlsym()`, especially with regard to the two "pseudo-handles". C++ objects use "mangled" names, so with C++ sources the symbol won't be simply "dvmDumpThreadStack". Use the `nm` command from the NDK (android-eabi-nm or something like that) with the -D flag to scan the dalvik .so for symbol names. You can use `c++filt` to demangle the names you find to confirm you have the right thing.